# Method string.Replace( ) doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, random

```
    public string Generate()
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator rdng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[40];

        rdng.GetBytes(bytes);

        string a = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); 

        a.Replace("=", "r");
        a.Replace("+", "t");

        return a;
    }

a=43TvtRvrTrt54g5gtbrTTBR45iu+zqbB03gXej== ;
```

after `a.Replace()` again:

```
a=43TvtRvrTrt54g5gtbrTTBR45iu+zqbB03gXej== ;
```

I want to generate unique value in my `C#` project.
Everything is great.
But When I want to call `string.Replace()`, it doesn't work.
Values after and before this method are the same.
Why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The replace method returns a new string object, it does not modify the existing string. The following statement should work:

```
a = a.Replace("=", "r");
```

Comment: ok thank you, but why I didn't get error if my writting is wrong ?

Comment: I will accept in 10 mitunes

Comment: @user3461906 because it isn't technically an *error* to call a method and ignore the return value

Comment: It is not an error to call a method and ignore the return value.

Comment: @user3461906 because its not necessary to use the return value, which is returned by Replace here

Answer (score 6):

It works. It just doesn't do what you think: it doesn't edit the *existing* `string`: it creates a *new* string. Try:

```
    a = a.Replace("=", "r");
    a = a.Replace("+", "t");
```

This is because `string`s are **immutable**: they do not change once created (at least, not if you might be looking - there are some exceptions like the internals of `StringBuilder`, but those are implementation details that you shouldn't see)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the method doesn't change the string you call the method on, but returns another occurrence of the string, so you should assign it to another object in order for the changes to persist because a string is a non mutable object:

```
a=a.Replace("=", "r");
a=a.Replace("+", "t");
```

Answer (score 2):

String.Replace is not modifying a, but returning a new String. As this makes it chainable, a solution could look like:

```
a = a.Replace("=", "r").Replace("+", "t");
```